# Как правильно написать: заказы получателей или заказы на получателей

Tags: грамотная-речь

Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант более правильный и почему:

"объединить заказы на разных получателей в одну посылку" или

"объединить заказы разных получателей в одну посылку", то есть с предлогом "на или без него?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

От смысла зависит. Если получатели - и есть те, кто заказывал, то это ***заказы получателей***.
Но если кто-то-то оформлял заказы ***на разных получателей*** - то логично эти заказы так и называть.
Насколько понимаю, второй вариант более жизненный.

Comment: Согласна с рассуждением. Но мне "на" не очень нравится. Я бы использовала "для". (Объединить заказы ДЛЯ разных получателей).

Comment: "0формить [что-то] на кого-то" - обычный канцелярско-юридический штамп. "Довеннность на кого-то". "имущество, оформенленное на супругов" и проч. Причин для возражений против такого использования не вижу. Тем более, что "для кого-то" и "на кого-то" - далеко не одно и то же.

Comment: Но здесь не совсем так. Я бы поставила вопрос от слова "заказы". Заказы (для кого?) для получателей.

Comment: >Но здесь не совсем так. ... Заказы (для кого?) для получателей. 
  
Совсем не уверен. Впрочем, этот вариант я тоже обговаривал.  
Но исходя из сути работы подобных служб доставки, полагаю, что им гораздо важнее "на кого" оформлен заказ, а не "для кого" он.

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: "объединить заказы разных получателей в одну посылку" или "заказы для разных получателей", чтобы понятнее было. Предлог НА лучше не употреблять, он уместен в предложении "получить заказ на одноразовые шприцы". А то получится, что мы получателей "заказываем".